# Is it safe to enable Contextual Links for all users?

Tags: 8

I've installed [lazy-load](https://www.drupal.org/project/lazy) module for images. And when users don't have `Contextual Links` permission they don't see images if module is enabled. Is it safe to give this permission to everybody?

Comment: It might be a problem with the theme try using a different theme to see if it gets resolved.  Otherwise it sounds like a bug/incompatibility between the two modules.  I would search whether it is a known bug and it might have a workaround.  If its not known it would help everyone if you posted it all details on the issue queue so someone can take a look at it and hopefully fix it.  It might also be a  third module's fault.  Try disabling any modules that are in beta/alpha stage perhaps you can find what module is at fault.